# Finding the intersection of a series of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there a general formula to find the interval which is the interesection of a series of sets?
I played around with the following:
$$A_k := \{n\in \mathbb{Z}:k\leq n \leq k^2 + 5\}$$
where $k = 1,2,\ldots$
Find $\bigcap_{k=1}^{90} A_k$.

$A_k = [k,k^2+5]$.
Playing around with a few values, I take the lower bound to be the maximum of the bottom bound which is $\max\{\cap_{k=1}^{90}k\}$.
Then the upper bound will be the minimum of $k^2 + 5$ as it ranges from $k=1$ to $90$, making sure it's bigger than our acquired lower bound. So
$$\bigcap_{k=1}^{90}A_k = \left(\{\max\{\bigcap_{k=1}^{90}k\},\left(\min\{\bigcap_{k=1}^{90}(k^2+5)\ \ \text{contingent on}\geq \max\{\bigcap_{k=1}^{90}k\}\right)\right)=[90,105].$$

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do with constructions such as $\bigcap_{k=1}^{90} k$.  The $k$ here are integers, not sets.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't sure how to phrase it in math language. I meant to mean "take the highest value for the function $k$" as $k$ ranges. Then for upper bound, "take lowest value for function $k^2+5$ as $k$ ranges making sure its bigger than the previous value found"

Comment: You don't have to make sure it is bigger.  If it isn't, your interval is empty.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, $\bigcup_{k=1}^{90}A_k$ is the **union** of the sets $A_k$
not their intersection.

$A_1=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $A_2=\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and so on, up to
$A_{90}=\{90,91,\ldots,90^2+5\}$. The union of these sets is the
collection of elements that occur in at least one of them, that is
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^{90}A_k=\{1,2,3,\ldots,90^2+5\}.$$

Comment: OOPS, they were actually all supposed to be intersection signs, sorry

Comment: @similarityinvariance1 So what is $A_1\cap A_{90}$?

Comment: Is it the empty set?

Answer (score 0):

If $A_k = \{n: a_k \le n \le b_k\}$, then $$\bigcap_{k=1}^K A_k = \{n: \max (a_1, \ldots, a_K) \le n \le \min(b_1, \ldots, b_K)\}$$

Note that if $\max(a_1,\ldots, a_K) > \min(b_1,\ldots,b_K)$ this is $\emptyset$.